# pjsip iPhone missing libraries

Tags: iphone, ios, voip

I am working on [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm) for voice chat on iPhone. The steps I have completed from [the instructions](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) are:

1. changed config_site.h as given.
2. successfully ran

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
   $ ./configure-iphone
   $ make dep && make clean && make
   ```
3. opened ipjsua.xcodeproj to build but some libraries are missing (highlighted in red). The project therefore does not build and I'm unable to proceed further.

[image: Screenshot for missing libraries]

How should I build project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could sort out the problem,
it wasnt big problem actually.

my project is not configured to run on simulator,so here are so many linking errors(these red colored librarys required to support pjsip on simulator).

i set my target as my ipad instead of simulator and made build.

it just worked!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the missing libraries, locate this libraries in your build directory and then add them again to your project.

Comment: there are no files in my project naming any of these librarys. and if i delete any of these 100s of linking error occurs